# Load data records from EXCEL to mssql database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, excel

**How can i load data records from excel file to mssql database?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your data types are consistent between the CSV columns and your database columns then a bulk insert would work.

```
BULK INSERT tablename
FROM 'C:\Temp\filename.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
MAXERRORS = 0,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**csv files are in ascii format and have some problem with unicode characters such as 'ی' – ramezani.saleh 26 mins ago** 
For this problem i must export my excel file to **Unicode text file** and then i must use

```
BULK INSERT tablename FROM 'C:\Temp\filename.txt' WITH ( FIRSTROW
= 2, MAXERRORS = 0, FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'  )
```

I thinks it works and the problem of csv files with unicode charcters will solve (such as 'ی')

Answer (score 0):

- Use [SQirreL SQL Client](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) (java based) + Excel JDBC driver (for example http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlsql/) and copy the data with a SQL script
- You can export an excel file to a csv
  file and import it via SQL

Comment: csv files are in ascii format and have some problem with unicode characters such as 'ی'

Comment: @ramezani.saleh I see. I updated my answer. SQirreL is a really great tool for that purpose, though I newver tried it with an excel JDBC driver